# Controller in other package ( CakePHP 2.1 )

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.1

At first sorry my bad English.

I want define routing for this url:

For example my controller is in "/app/Controller/**Services**/TypesController.php"

My controller has 2 action

**index**() and **property**();

How to define routing for this url:

/**services**/types/**property**

/**services**/types/**index**

Comment: you mean `TypesController.php` aren't you? and 'index()' etc? the casing is very important in programming - and so in cakephp

Comment: yes sorry,its my bad.i've edited it

Comment: no problem. the correct spelling helps to focus on the actual issue (instead of pointing out what else could be fixed/improved)

Comment: Your word is true. tanx for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot create subfolders in /Controller

It is just

```
/app/Controller/TypesController.php
```

url result:

```
/types/action/
```

OR - you can make it a plugin:

```
/app/Plugin/Services/Controller/TypesController.php
```

url result:

```
/services/types/action/
```

but thats pretty well documented: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html

Comment: there is no way? for example with routes.php?

Comment: it doesnt have to do with routes that you cannot make subfolders in the controller directory. you can match the routes to your need, of course. but your initial layout of files is still wrong. you first need to fix this, then you can start working with the routes until you are satisfied.

Comment: @mark You can indeed use folders in the controller folder, just use `App::build()` to point to new paths (or use https://github.com/ichikaway/AutoAppBuild to automatically do so). Although it doesn't solve the OP's question.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, you could easily use routes to point `/services/types/index` to the `TypesController`. The folder wouldn't matter, per se, but would look how the OP wanted and maintain his folder structure.

Comment: well, of course you can start hacking around with App::build. But I don't think there is a good reason to proceed this way here (in my opinion anyway). I think he does mean "plugins" with his "packages" idea. he just has to start doing it the cake way.

Comment: tanx for your comment,
i think plugin is good solution for me because I'm not into other problems (layouts and views).
But I wanted a general routing for my subfolders in controller folder but it is rather difficult.
By the way, thanks for your help